# Normal vector of cylinderical graph

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Assume $\{e_1,...,e_{n+1}\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Then, 
$L=\{x\in \mathbb R^{n+1} : |x-\langle x, e_1 \rangle e_1 |=1 \}$ is n-cylinder of radius 1. Consider a smooth function $f:L\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)>-1 , \forall x\in L$. Then we have a cylinderical graph of $f$ i.e.
$$
G_f=\{(x_1,(1+f)x_2,...,(1+f)x_{n+1})\in \mathbb R^{n+1} : \forall (x_1,...,x_{n+1}) \in L\}
$$
Then, how to calculate the normal vector of $G_f$ ?

What I try :

$\forall x \in L$, $x_{n+1}$ can be written as $\sqrt{1-\sum\limits_{i=2}^nx_i^2}$. So  $L$ can be presented as 
$$
\{(x_1,x_2,....,x_n,\sqrt{1-\sum\limits_{i=2}^nx_i^2} ~)\in \mathbb R^{n+1}:  1-\sum\limits_{i=2}^nx_i^2\ge 0\}
$$ 
Equivalently, $(x_1,...,x_n)$ is cylindrical coordinates of $L$. Then the graph $G_f$ can be treat as 
$$
u:(x_1,...,x_n)\rightarrow (x_1,(1+f)x_2,...,(1+f)\sqrt{1-\sum\limits_{i=2}^nx_i^2})
$$
Then $\{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\}_{i=1}^n$ are basis of tangent space of $L$. Theoretically, I can get the normal vector, but it is hard to calculate and has complex form.

**Are there  any simple expression liking the normal vector of the graph of function on plane i.e. $\nu=\frac{(-\nabla f , 1)}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f |^2}}$ ?**

Comment: Do you know the answer in the simple cases $n=2,3$? You should be able to guess the generalization quite easily and then check it's correct.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  I just know the case $n=2$. Because $\sqrt{1-\sum\limits_{i=2}^nx_i^2} \ge 0$, I think the above presentation is not suitable. So, let $(x,\theta)$ is the local coordinate of cylinder, and $(x,\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ is the coodinate in $\mathbb R^3$.  Then, I get the $\nu = \{ff_x, -f_\theta \sin\theta+f\cos\theta, f_\theta\cos\theta - f\sin\theta\}$.  Whether this coodinate is suitable for calculating the case $n=3$ ?

Comment: Oh, I was assuming $f$ was a function of $x_1$ alone. In general I think the first component will always be $f f_x$, and the rest can probably be expressed nicely in terms of the gradient of a slice of $f$ considered as a function on $\mathbb S^{n-1}$.